# How to flag a method to be required to overload when inheriting in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to tell the future programmer the following class methods must be overridden if the AbstractCrawler is inherited.

```
class AbstractCrawler(object):

    def get_playlist_videos():
        pass

    def get_related_videos():
        pass

    def create_playlists():
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the class and its methods as [abstract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractCrawler(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_playlist_videos(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_related_videos(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def create_playlists(self):
        pass
```

Then:

```
class ImplCrawler(AbstractCrawler):
    pass

>>> i = ImplCrawler()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ImplCrawler with abstract methods create_playlists, get_playlist_videos, get_related_videos
```

Compared to:

```
class ImplCrawler(AbstractCrawler):
    def get_playlist_videos(self):
        pass

    def get_related_videos(self):
        pass

    def create_playlists(self):
        pass

>>> i = ImplCrawler()
# No error
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question. However, do you know if I can do this without the extra overhead and confusion of making the extra class ImplCrawler.
I feel the need for extra class just as a wrapper makes this even more confusing.

Comment: @brikas `ImplCrawler` was just an example of someone trying to subclass your ABC. You'd only need `AbstractCrawler` for your code.